# Is it possible to use "throws" on a method in an external JAR

Tags: java, exception, jar

I have a separate JAR library with a collection of methods that throw custom exceptions, for example:

```
public String methodName() throws CustomException {
    // code here
}
```

I then add the JAR to the classpath and reference the library method within a try statement in source code:

```
try {
    DemoClass demoClass = new DemoClass ();
    demoClass.methodName() // this should throw a CustomException if something occurs
} catch (CustomException e) {
    // something here
}
```

The above code snippet keeps returning the following compilation error:

> CustomException is never thrown in the body of corresponding try statement

If the method is in the local context (not packaged in a JAR) the code works.. So my question, is it possible to "throw" custom exceptions from JAR libraries?

Comment: The class you referred to in your try block, is it `java.lang.Class` or some placeholder for a class?

Comment: It is a placeholder, example has been updated.

Comment: The only thing could be there are DemoClass one in jar one in code and either one of them has methodName() which does not throw exception.

Comment: does "compilation error" mean "when executing javac" or "my IDE says so"?

Comment: Kai: building with maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter whether the your class is in a jar or in the local context, it can always throw exceptions. You should check if you are using the class and calling the method that you intend to and not some other class and some other method with same name.

My hunch is something like `ParseException` which is in both `java.text.ParseException` and in `org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException` and when `demoClass.methodName()` actually throws the former, you would have imported the latter in your code and trying to catch it and that is what the compiler is complaining about. You may want to check all the locations where the CustomException is present and you are trying to catch the right one.

Comment: The project is very modular so this is definitely not the case unfortunately.

Comment: I think it's time you get into specific names for us to get a better understanding. Please see the edit in my update.

Comment: The MyClass and CustomException are packaged in different JARs (pointed out below), is this an issue?

Comment: Even that should not be an issue at all!

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using "class" as it is a reserved keyword.

```
try {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.methodName() // this should throw a CustomException if something occurs
} catch (CustomException e) {
    // something here
}
```

Also, make sure you are importing "MyClass" and "CustomException" from the same jar and that your snippet and "MyClass" imports "CustomException" from the same package.

Comment: MyClass and the customException are not being imported from the same JAR, is this the issue?

Comment: Not necessarily, you shouldn't have any problem if both jars are in the classpath.
In fact, an error in the import clauses is more probable.
Check if DemoClass imports CustomException from the same package than your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `CustomException` is a checked exception, but compiler is seeing a version of the `DemoClass.methodName()` is not **declared** as throwing that exception.  The compiler then deduces that since the signature of the method doesn't allow the exception to be thrown, it **cannot** be thrown.

If you want to be able to catch that checked exception there, then the exception (or a superclass) must be included in the `throws` clause of the method declaration for the class that you compile against.

---

> MyClass and the customException are not being imported from the same JAR, is this the issue?

Not *per se*.

However, I suspect you've actually got two different (incompatible) versions of the relevant class or interface in the two JARs.  That would be a mistake.  Even if you managed to get it to compile, you would most likely run into classloader problems due to the signature conflict.